# Upper bound on expected value $E[X^2]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus

> Assume $X_n$ is a sequence of positive random variables such that $E[X_n]=\mathcal{O}(f(n))$ as ${n \to \infty}$, where $f$ is a function. Is the following true? If yes, prove it:
>   $$E[X_n^2]=\mathcal{O}(f^2(n))\text{ as } {n \to \infty}$$
>   If it is not generally true, is there a set of assumptions under which the above equation is true?

Using Jensen's inequality: $E[X_n^2]\geq E[X_n]^2$ which does not help. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: This makes no sense as stated.  The left side does not depend on $n$, while the right side does.  Anyway, what if $E[X_n] = 0$?  $E[X_n^2]$ could be as large as you want.

Comment: I think the correct way to pose the question is to say $E[X_n] = \mathcal O(f(n))$ as $n \to \infty$, without the limit. We could have $E[X_n]=0$, but often you want asymptotic bounds on $E[X_n^2]$ for nonnegative random variables, where the claim is *still* false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About all you can say is this.  If $0 \le X \le b$ a.s., then
$\mathbb E[X^2] \le b\; \mathbb E[X]$.  This is best possible, in that equality holds when the only possible values of $X$ are $0$ and $b$.

Comment: @ Thanks. But, I needed $E[X^2]\leq c E[X]^2$

Comment: OK, this is true if in addition $\mathbb E[X] \ge 1$.

Comment: Hi Robert, out of curiosity: could you please give a pointer to a proof of the inequality given in your answer? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Since $X^2 \le bX$ a.s., $\mathbb E[X^2] \le \mathbb E[bX]=b \mathbb E[X]$.

Answer (score 0):

It's false. For example, setting $X_n$ to be $n$ with probability $\frac1n$ and $0$ otherwise gives us $E[X_n] = 1$ for all $n$, but $E[X_n^2] = n$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a set of assumptions under which the above equation is true?

Comment: Usually, it goes the other way: having an upper bound on $E[X^2]$ is a simple assumption telling you that $X$ is well-behaved in other, more complicated ways. (Note that it's even possible that $E[X]$ is finite but $E[X^2]$ is not!)

Comment: I am actively looking for the set of assumptions that make this valid.